# Azure Application Insights - search HTTP erros?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Is there a way to use Application Insights as a substitute for `Web Server Logging`? My end goal here is to analyze 4xxs and 5xxs.

Details:
-Right now, i only have the requests info for controllers/action where I manually used `TrackRequest`
-Web App hosted on Azure.
-SDK added as documents instruct.
-Other parts (SQL Dependency Tracking for example) work out-of-the-box

Comment: What do you mean? If you add it your web app it will log all requests and their status codes. So yes, you should be able to do some diagnosing.

Comment: @PeterBons actually no... it's only logging the ones i'm creating via "TrackRequest"...

Comment: Where and how is your website ( I assume that is what it is) hosted? Can't you integrate application insights so you do not have to use the SDK? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps. That way it will capture all info like exceptions and requests etc.

Comment: @PeterBons check updates pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the web.config was missing:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
```